# How do I convert the following to a valid JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

Given

```
var test = '{key1: "val1", data:{ key2: "val2", key3: "val3" }}' => returned by third party library 

expectedOutput = {key1: "val1", data:{ key2: "val2", key3: "val3" }}
```

I tried JSON.parse(test) => throws error 
I tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test)) => returns string double parsing results error.

What am I missing ?

How do I get a JSON and not a string by parsing ?

Comment: If the third party library is returning that... there's your trouble.  That string is not valid JSON.  Either: it claims it is returning JSON (in error, but because it isn't), or you are assuming it "should be" JSON because it looks like it (but it isn't).

Comment: what 3rd party library is this, that returns the invalid JSON?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test)))` is this not working for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you likely need to quote your keys:

```
var test = '{"key1": "val1", "data":{ "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3" }}'
```

Not all but many JSON parsers expect the keys to be quoted

Comment: JSON expressly requires double quoted keys.  If a JSON parser allows it, it is being non-compliant with the JSON specification.

Comment: @DanH yes, though that wasn't always the case. The standardization is fairly recent (considering the age of JSON) JSON was around 13 years old before being standardized prior to that it was simply "*J*ava*S*cript *O*bject *N*otation" which allows non-quoted keys

Comment: @RunsFS: if the OP is relying on a library that is over 13 years old and hasn't been updated since then, he probably has bigger problems that outdated JSON compliance!  That said: I'm suspecting the library is not INTENDING to output JSON, and the OP just assumed it was.

Comment: @DanH yes depending on a 13 year old library would be odd but I don't know why you think that. I said that JSON was around for 13 years _before_ the standard. That means there's quite a lot of code out there that might actually depend on a non-compliant library (or more precisely a backwards compatible library) not saying that's the case here nor was I in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "s around the keys

Wrong:
`JSON.parse('{key1: "val1", data:{ key2: "val2", key3: "val3" }}')`

Right:
`JSON.parse('{"key1": "val1", "data":{ "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3" }}')`

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes to the keys because the parser needs them -

```js
var test = '{"key1": "val1", "data":{ "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3" }}'
console.log(JSON.parse(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

To your question: how can I get valid JSON to start with?

I say... use `JSON.stringify()`.

That is, if you are just learning JSON (seems like you are), then use `JSON.stringify()` as a teaching tool.

In your console, type:

```
obj = {key1: "val1", data:{ key2: "val2", key3: "val3" }}
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

And you will see the result is valid JSON:

```
'{"key1":"val1","data":{"key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}}'
```

From this, you could see you were missing the double quotes around the keys.

Comment: I know about JSON stringify. As I mentioned above I did first stringify and then parse. but the output was still a double encoded string

Comment: @user2821242 : your code is different from mine.  Your code sends a JavaScript STRING of invalid JSON to `stringify`.  My code sends a JavaScript OBJECT to `stringify`.  If you don't know the difference.... you are still learning.

Comment: yes I know it is invalid JSON and that invalid JSON string is passed from a third party which I have no control over. hence the question! but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with that library returning what looks like a JavaScript value in a string, you could use JavaScript's `eval()`, like this:

```
# nominal return value -- valid JavaScript in a string (that isn't JSON) 
var rval_str = '{key1: "val1", data:{ key2: "val2", key3: "val3" }}'
# use eval() to 'decode' rval_str
eval("rval = " + rval_str)
rval
```

gives

```
{key1: "val1", data:{ key2: "val2", key3: "val3" }}
```

Of course, this is very risky (using `eval`) if you don't trust what the library is returning.